# SQL Server 2019 Enterprise - High Availability with Master Key

Tags: sql-server, high-availability

I have a SQL Server 2019 Enterprise HA system that has a encrypted master key, and every time that I have to fail over to the secondary database (or vice n versa) I have to run this script in order to have the Secondary working after the failover.

```
DROP SYMMETRIC KEY DataProtectionKey 
DROP CERTIFICATE DataProtection
DROP MASTER KEY

CREATE MASTER KEY ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD = 'My_encryption_key'
    CREATE CERTIFICATE DataProtection WITH SUBJECT = 'Data Protection'
    CREATE SYMMETRIC KEY DataProtectionKey WITH ALGORITHM = AES_256 ENCRYPTION BY CERTIFICATE DataProtection


USE [MYDATABASE]
GO

ALTER MASTER KEY FORCE REGENERATE 
WITH ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD = 'My_encryption_key'
GO
```

I also tried to use this other script after failing over to see if I could finally insert the Master Key and solve for all the issue.

```
USE [MYDATABASE]
GO
 
OPEN MASTER KEY DECRYPTION BY PASSWORD = 'My_encryption_key';
ALTER MASTER KEY DROP ENCRYPTION BY SERVICE MASTER KEY
ALTER MASTER KEY ADD ENCRYPTION BY SERVICE MASTER KEY
CLOSE MASTER KEY;
```

Unfortunately, every time that I fail over the DB, I have to run one of the two scripts.

There is any way that I could do this once for all ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can try to create the certificate on primary, backup, and restore on secondary.

This code is from my [repo](https://github.com/m4ss1m0g/DockerCompose_SqlServer_AlwaysOn) created for a demo for AlwaysOn with docker.

### Primary

```
-- PRIMARY
USE [master]
GO

-- Create masterkey
CREATE MASTER KEY ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD = 'P@ssw0rd!';
GO

-- Create certificate
CREATE CERTIFICATE ao_certificate WITH SUBJECT = 'ao_certificate';
GO

BACKUP CERTIFICATE ao_certificate
TO FILE = '/var/opt/mssql/shared/ao_certificate.cert'
WITH PRIVATE KEY (
        FILE = '/var/opt/mssql/shared/ao_certificate.key',
        ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD = 'P@ssw0rd!'
    );
GO
```

### Secondary

```
-- SECONDARY
USE [master]
GO

-- Create master key
CREATE MASTER KEY ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD = 'P@ssw0rd!';
GO

-- create certificate with private key created on primary server and saved to shared location
CREATE CERTIFICATE ao_certificate
    FROM FILE = '/var/opt/mssql/shared/ao_certificate.cert'
    WITH PRIVATE KEY (
    FILE = '/var/opt/mssql/shared/ao_certificate.key',
    DECRYPTION BY PASSWORD = 'P@ssw0rd!'
)
GO
```

Comment: I will test this when I return back to the office.
I was on-site on a PROD environment and as soon as I test this, I will post here.

Thank you so much.

Comment: Sorry for being late, but was not onsite and I could not test the solution.
Here what I've done.

When I failover to the secondary the application still ask for the MASTER_KEY and I had to re-do all again.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, and the fix is relatively simple. Take a backup of the service master key (SMK) from the secondary replica and restore it to the primary replica. This will re-encrypt anything already encrypted with the existing SMK with the restored SMK. And since the SMK is now the same between both replicas, the failover will be seamless.

The reason that the direction is from secondary to primary is that the re-encryption performs writes (albeit not many) into your user database which is allowed only on the primary replica.

Answer (score 0):

A colleague from my team found a better solution for this issue.

1. On the primary DB, I will call DBS1 backup the master key using the encryption password that you used to create the DB:

   ```sql
   BACKUP SERVICE MASTER KEY TO FILE = 'D:\Backup\dbs1_service_master_key.key' ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD = 'Wh@t3v3r_P@$$w0rd';
   ```
2. Promote the secondary DB to primary on the HA (failover), so you can run the script below:

   ```sql
   USE [YOURDATABASE]
   GO
   open master key decryption by password = 'Wh@t3v3r_P@$$w0rd'
   Alter Master Key Add encryption by Service Master Key
   GO
   ```
3. Copy the service master key that you backed up on the primary DBS1 and copy in a location on DBS2.
   Still on the "secondary" DBS that now is primary on the HA group, restore the certificate:

   ```
   RESTORE SERVICE MASTER KEY FROM FILE = 'D:\Backup\dbs1_service_master_key.key' DECRYPTION BY PASSWORD = 'Wh@t3v3r_P@$$w0rd';
   ```